# Complete a colum with http call

Tags: angular, promise, angular8, angular-promise

I have a table in angular 8 and to complete one column I have to do a http call. Now the column is

```
<td>{{getContractExcternalReference(orderFiltered.contractId)}}</td>
```

and the method is

```
  async getContractExcternalReference(contractId){
    const data = await this.contractService.getContract(this.subdistributor.id, contractId).toPromise();
    return data.externalReference;
  }
```

I can't complete this column, or is empty or show this: *[object Promise]*

Some idea to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) instead of converting your Observable to a promise.

The template would look like this:

```
<td>{{ (contractService.getContract(subdistributor.id, orderFiltered.contractId) | async).externalReference }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, the call runs, but there are a error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'externalReference' of null

Comment: Add a ? before .externalReference if your function has a possibility of returning null